# In Javascript, If function is object data type (derived), then how it is used as Object constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, built-in, circular-reference

My understanding is, In javascript functions are objects. With that understanding I have written code for years. Suddenly this question comes to mind
`typeof Object` is `function`, but a `function` is an object. We create an object with a (constructor) function (which is an object). So which one comes first? object or function? chicken or egg?

How is this working actually? Seems like a circular reference?

Comment: Not really a circular reference unless you want to go all philosophical on it. A function you can execute, an object you can interact with in other ways. That's enough of a distinction for practically all cases. So, yes - a function can be an object *and* a function because you can execute it and also interact with it as an object. Since you basically only care for execution, `typeof` reports that.

Comment: Everything is an Object. Consider it the base type. Like "made of atoms". Everything is a type of thing "made of atoms". However, factories (like the one in China that make iPhones) are also things "made of atoms" but they are special. They can produce iPhones, cars, TV, computers, knives etc. So even though Functions are Objects you can use Functions in a special way compared to other types of Objects like Numbers, Strings, HTMLElement, Promise etc. Now, in the real world we can't quite directly make things out of atoms - we need to do it higher up like make them out of wood or glass...

Comment: ... but in javascript we can directly create things out of Object. Kind of like replicators in Star Trek that directly make things out of atoms. Yes, replicators can make things out of atoms but it is by its very existence is also made out of atoms.

Answer (score 1):

The `Object` constructor function is provided by the underlying JS engine and is not created as part of the JavaScript program.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Object` and `Function` are constructor functions. Like all functions they are typeof 'function'. Because of the prototype hierarchy, they are also both instances of both `Function` and `Object`:

```js
console.log(Object instanceof Object)   // true
console.log(Object instanceof Function) // true

console.log(Function instanceof Object)   // true
console.log(Function instanceof Function) // true
```

This is because functions are prototype-linked to the Object prototype.

Now when you *call* `Object()`, it creates an object, not a function:

```js
let o = Object()
console.log(typeof o)              // object
console.log(o instanceof Object)   // true
console.log(o instanceof Function) // false

let f = Function()
console.log(typeof f)              // función
console.log(f instanceof Object)   // true
console.log(f instanceof Function) // true because of prototype linking
```

So there's no circular reference, just some confusing names. Objects are not instances of functions, but there is a function called `Object()` that you can call to produce object instances. The hierarchy is Object -> Function. Functions inherit from Objects but both `Object` and `Function` are constructor functions that produce instances of their corresponding types.

Comment: So a construction function is different from a normal function? I mean Object(), Function() are functions and are different from functions that are declared with `function` keyword? But we use it to declare custom constructor function?

```
Function instanceof Function // true
Function instanceof Object // true
Object instanceof Object // true
Object instanceof Function //true
```

Above is in chrome developer tool

Comment: You can declare your own constructor functions: `function Something(){}` and then call it with `new` : `new Something() instanceof Something // true`.

Answer (score 0):

> We create an object with a (constructor) function (which is an object). So which one comes first? object or function? chicken or egg? Seems like a circular reference?

We can create objects with constructors, yes, but that's not the only way. Consider object literals.
We can create functions with the `Function` constructor function object, yes, but that's not the only way. Functions are usually created using function definitions.

So no, you neither need objects to create functions, nor do you need functions to create objects. In a typical JS program, they come in the order they are defined/evaluated in.

However you may ask about `Object` and `Function`. Yes, they have circular references set up between them and their prototype objects, but that's not a chicken-or-egg problem either. You can create circular references by trivial assignments. They don't really depend on each other, it's not like one was used to create the other. They came into existence separately. Which came first? We don't know, they are both builtin objects created by the environment. We don't care, they both already exist when our code runs.