# Order of creation of Constructor object and prototype Object

Tags: javascript

Let us say I this Javascript code:

```
function Dog(){}
let d1 = new Dog();
```

Now, 5 objects are what I need to analyse -

1. `Dog` Constructor object
2. `Dog.prototype` object
3. `Object` Constructor object
4. `Object.prototype` object
5. `d1` object

What is the order of their creation ?

Comment: Second line has incorrect syntax, you should use var, const or let to declare the d1 object and assign the instance of Dog to it.

Comment: thnx @YalungTang. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object` and `Object.prototype` come first, they are builtins and [just exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54960209/1048572) - before any user code would run.

`Dog` and `Dog.prototype` are created at once, together, when the function is getting declared (during the creation of the scope).

`d1`, the object created by the constructor call to `Dog` and inheriting from `Dog.prototype`, is instantiated last (during the execution of the code).

Comment: So, `Dog` and `Dog.prototype` are created simultaneously ? But I heard JavaScript is single threaded. How it creates 2 objects simultaneously? I am new to Javascript so I might be wrong here.

Comment: @Number945 Not in parallel, in a multithreaded environment, no. But they are getting created at the same instant, and you cannot distinguish which one comes first from js code. Of course the js engine will create them in some order, but it is arbitrary (might differ between different engines) and does not matter because it is not observable.